# data visualization across time dimension

Tags: sql, pandas, data-visualization

We have

```
set A  
set B 
time dimension T
```

We like to see

```
A minus B 
B minus A
A intersect B

across Time T
```

So far we only use excel to plot out the period we like to compare.

E.g. let say the grains are one month for the time dimension.

If we are comparing

1. Between 2019Q1 vs 2019Q2
2. Between 2019Q2 vs 2019Q3
3. Between 2019Q3 vs 2019Q4

We would have 9 excel file generated.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: This would be a very good example of a bad question :-). Please include a sample data and expected output.

Comment: Do you have access to Tableau?

Comment: @Kaish. Yes for Tableau.

Comment: @Quang Hoang https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eZ0oPderfibu3FbJjHwBc6xIzzLwGhdeTITQ4-Mh2eo/edit?usp=sharing